# PHP - Recursive function using same variable as the last call

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm using a recursive function inside a class. The function change the value of a variable `$estados`. In the first call, everything is ok, in the second call the function change the values of the variable of the last call of the function.

This is my code.

```
class Trab3Code
{
    public function fechoEpsilon($automato, $estado)
    {
        $estados = $automato->transicao($estado, '&');
        $fechos = array();
        if (!empty($estados)) {
            foreach ($estados as $elemento) {
                $fechos[] = $this->fechoEpsilon($automato, $elemento);
            }
        }

        $estados[] = $estado;

        return array_unique(array_merge($estados, $fechos));
    }
}
```

I get the new values of the `$estado` variable from a function of the `$automato` variable. The return of the function is a array. In the first run, everything is ok. In the second run, the return of the function will be a empty array, and that overrides the previously value of the first run.

Can anyone help me?

---EDIT---

The first call of my function is `fechoEpsilon($automato, 0)`.
That being said the value of `$estados` should contain at least:

```
array(
    0 => 1
    1 => 3
)
```

Which is the result of the first call
But what I'm getting is a empty array. Or a array with only the `0` value, which is setted in this line

```
$estados[] = $estado;
```

Sorry if it looks to complicated, this a work about automatas. The `fechoEpsilon` function calculate the Epsilon Closure of a state inside the automata.

And I know that the value is changing, don't know how, but it is. If I dump the value of the variable over the call, it will change, and in the end, my final value is the one from the last call, which is a empty array. 
Sorry about the static method call, was my mistake, I was using with `$this`. I updated the code.

Comment: `$estados` is a local variable. Changing it in the recursive call has no effect on the original call.

Comment: You're statically calling `Trab3Code::fechoEpsilon` although it's not a static method

Comment: @Manulaiko Since the method never uses `$this`, it can be used like a static method.

Comment: @Barmar It still works, but is bad practice and will issue an `E_STRICT` message.

Comment: I can't understand you description of the problem. Can you show the input data, the result you're getting, and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Sry for the delay, I edited the question, putted some more informations. Now I don't have much time, but tomorrow I will try to show all the data that goes through the `$estados` variable.

Comment: A recursive function requires a stopping condition, here this is not clear because it relies on the call of.$automato->transicao(). Use a better condition to stop it and some echo to get the source of the problem. As this is in portugesh (?), I am unable to understand the logic :-P

Comment: The conditions is the $automato->transicao() returning a empty array. Which will always happen given a valid automato (which always happen). And yes, it is portuguese, the logic is a little bit messy without the previously knowledge about the functions and other classes.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what happen, I took out the array_unique function and now everything woks just fine. Thank you all for the help o/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have no idea what happen, I took out the array_unique function and now everything woks just fine.

Apparently there was a problem with using array_unique, because in some part of the code I was getting a array inside array. Which somehow bugged everything.

Thank you all for the help o/